# Networking in raspberry pi over Ethernet and UART at the same time

Tags: networking, pi-2

Is it possible to have two simultaneous networking connections (one over Ethernet and other over UART using UART to Ethernet adapter)? I also want to know if these two connections can have different IP addresses over the network.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have two simultaneous networking connections

Yes, but you need to have different addresses for the different interfaces (which answers your second question).

*However*, you probably want to set up routing if you want this to work for any particular purpose.  Questions about that are better off on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/); **make sure you are clear about specifically what it is you want to do** beyond just connecting to the same subnet twice (or two different subnets, as the case may be).